# How to detect akka actor termination is due to system shutdown and avoid restarting it

Tags: java, akka, akka-actor

I have a Spring application that makes use of a small Akka actor system (using Java), where I have a `MasterActor` that extends Akka's `AbstractActor` that initialises a `Router` and sets up a few worker actors. It also watches the lifecycle of the workers. I want to restart a Worker actor if it happens to die because of some `Exception`.

```
 public MasterActor(ActorPropsFactory actorPropsFactory) {
    this.actorPropsFactory = actorPropsFactory;

    int workers = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1;

    List<Routee> routees = Stream.generate(this::createActorRefRoutee).limit(workers).collect(Collectors.toList());

    this.router = new Router(new ConsistentHashingRoutingLogic(getContext().system()), routees);
  }

  private ActorRefRoutee createActorRefRoutee() {
    ActorRef worker = getContext().actorOf(actorPropsFactory.create(getWorkerActorClass()));
    getContext().watch(worker);
    return new ActorRefRoutee(worker);
  }

  private void route(Object message, Supplier<String> routingKeySupplier) {
    String routingKey = routingKeySupplier.get();
    RouterEnvelope envelope = new ConsistentHashingRouter.ConsistentHashableEnvelope(message, routingKey);
    router.route(envelope, getSender());
  }

 @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
        .match(
            EventMessage.class,
            message -> this.route(message, () -> message.getEvent().getId().toString()))
        .match(
            Terminated.class,
            message -> {
              logger.info("WorkerActor {} terminated, restarting", message.getActor());
              // todo: detect whether the system is shutting down before restarting the actor
              router = router.removeRoutee(message.actor())
                             .addRoutee(createActorRefRoutee());
            })
        .build();
  }
```

The problem I am having is that if the Spring Application fails to start up. (For example it fails to connect to the database, or some credentials are incorrect or something), I am receiving the `Terminated` message from all workers, and the Master actor tries to start new ones, which also get `Terminated` immediately, going into an endless loop.

What is the correct way to detect such scenario? Is there a way for the Master actor detect that the actor system is shutting down so that the workers are not restarted again?

Comment: Can't you just send a msg to master actor when you detect a startup failure?

Comment: @plalx Well it's not easy to detect startup failure. Dependencies could fail for a number of reasons and the whole point of using a dependency injection framework like Spring is to abstract away from the boiler plate of resolving and loading dependencies. I could hack around it with a shutdown hook, but I really want to understand what is actually sending the terminate message in the first place to my workers and whether there is some state information which could tell me why the actor was terminated in order to determine whether it makes sense to restart it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just set up a supervision strategy for your Router so you can inspect the type of Exception that causes the failure? This way you also don't need to restart your workers manually.

EDIT:

You set up `SupervisorStrategy` like this:

```
private static SupervisorStrategy strategy=
    new OneForOneStrategy(
    10,
    Duration.ofMinutes(1),
    DeciderBuilder.match(ArithmeticException.class,e->SupervisorStrategy.resume())
    .match(NullPointerException.class,e->SupervisorStrategy.restart())
    .match(IllegalArgumentException.class,e->SupervisorStrategy.stop())
    .matchAny(o->SupervisorStrategy.escalate())
    .build());
final ActorRef router=
        system.actorOf(
        new RoundRobinPool(5).withSupervisorStrategy(strategy).props(Props.create(Echo.class)));
```

You can read more about it here:

[Router Actor supervision](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/routing.html#supervision)

[Fault tolerance in Akka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/fault-tolerance.html)

Comment: How do you do that? (Sorry I am relatively new to Akka)

Comment: @jbx edited with example taken from Akka documentation and link to articles about SupervisorStrategy and supervision in Router. I hope it will help.